# Aigrette de vent

Tags: vocabulaire

Dans *L'amour fou* d'André Breton, on y lit cette phrase :

> J’avoue mon insensibilité profonde en présence des œuvres d’art qui, d’emblée, ne me procurent pas un trouble physique caractérisé par la sensation d’une aigrette de vent aux tempes.

Qu'est-ce qu'une aigrette de vent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Il doit falloir reconnaitre dans cette construction deux métaphores ; le mot « aigrette » a beaucoup été utilisé de cette manière, comme, par exemple, le montre le sens suivant du mot.

> ([TlFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/aigrette)) 2. HYDRAULIQUE. **Aigrette d'eau**. Petit jet d'eau en forme d'aigrette

Pour qu'un souffle puisse n'être senti qu'aux tempes, il doit être très faible, localisé dans un très petit volume de l'espace environnant, et donc, comparé à un souffle qui remuerait toute la chevelure, et qui serait un plumeau, ce n'est qu'une aigrette. Il faut, de plus prendre cette « aigrette de vent » comme étant un terme figuré puisqu'il s'agit d'une impression faite par une œuvre d'art ; il s'agit d'un sens figuré dans un sens figuré. L'auteur doit donc vouloir parler d'une sensation de saisissement de son esprit qui s'éveille tout d'un coup à une réalité artistique surprenante, inhabituellement stimulante, un peu comme un souffle qui caresse la peau éveille le sens du toucher (le plus souvent agréablement).

**Note** Cette image est réminiscences d'une autre, que l'on trouve dans un contexte culinaire dans un film de Laurel et Hardy, et où le cuisinier parle d'un souffle d'ail en tant qu'ingrédient dans  une préparation de côtelettes.